# SQL Server columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `ClassificationCode` and it has columns:

- `CodeName` and its continent name of codes I have
- `CodeType` and its continent type of codes from 1 to 5 and each number reference to code name

And when I use where condition to specify the name it works

```
Select code name 
from classification code 
where code type = 2 ;
```

My problem is if I could to repeat the code name in different condition like this

```
Select 
    code name, code name as 2, code name as 3 
from 
    classification code 
where 
    code type = 2  And code type = 3 and code type=4...
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Query to select the code name more three time with deffrent data

Comment: show us sample data and expected output.

Comment: `Select [code name] from [classification code] 
where [code type] in (2, 3, 4)` will return 3 rows. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have 2 options.  First if you want multiple rows, use `in` (which is equivalent to `or` instead of `and`):

```
select code_name from classification_code where code_type in (2,3,4)
```

---

Or if you are trying to `pivot` your results into a single row, here's an option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select max(case when code_type = 2 then code_name end) code_name_1,
       max(case when code_type = 3 then code_name end) code_name_2,
       max(case when code_type = 4 then code_name end) code_name_3
from classification_code
where code_type in (2,3,4)
```